# Empty (val) html field with ajax and enter next value in that field from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am working on student management system, so in my HTML form i have so many fields including the following

- Student Id
- Paper Number
- Score

The `HTML FORM` is using Ajax to submit the form data therefore i would like when the form is submitted `to empty (val) student id field and fill the student id field with next student id from MySQL` as well val Score field.

My Problem here is how to fill the student id field with next value from MySQL.

If that the from is not submitted via Ajax i would have just fetch and echo the next value from MySQL database.

The following is the Ajax Code am using to submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#keyingForm").submit(function() {
            $("#loading").slideDown();
                 var frm = $('#keyingForm');
                 $.ajax({
                     type: frm.attr('method'),
                     url: 'scoring.php',
                     data: frm.serialize(),
                     success: function (data) {
                         $('#loadData').html(data);
                         $("#loading").slideUp();
               }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              console.log(" The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown );
            } });
           return false;
        });
    });     
</script>
```

The student id field ID is `studentid` and score for `scoreid` field
I hope this makes sense as am not good on Ajax or JavaScript, Thanks for your hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On your PHP succes try load the following js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#studentid').val(''); $('#x1').val(''); 
        var tav    = $('#studentid').val(),
        strPos     = $('#studentid')[0].selectionStart;
        front      = (tav).substring(0,strPos),
        back       = (tav).substring(strPos,tav.length); 
        $('#studentid').val(front + "<?php echo $newstudentid; ?>" + $(this).text() + '' + back);               
    //});
</script>
```